# Can multiple applications be launched under the same package?

Tags: android, apk

I have an android app that is active on the playstore and I want to use the same code base (packages and everything) and publish another app which would be a different app on the play store. The new app would use most of the code from the older app but would also have newer functionalities added to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package id is a unique id for google play, you can't upload two apps with one package.

Instead of this use library projects or create different [flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Use on your new app all your abstract classes and interfaces and implement them properly but dont forget to put them in a new package. No one is gonna tell you not to do it couse no one knows or understands that you are extening another application. Good luck